# could heartbeat v3 monitor service/resource status without pacemaker?

Tags: centos, high-availability, heartbeat, linux-ha, heartbeat3

I am trying to setup a HA system based on CentOS, I want to use heartbeat v3 for the "heartbeat" mechanism, resource start/stop, looks heartbeat can get it done.
But about the resource status, heartbeat cannot monitor it, for example httpd, we manually stop it, but it cannot be restarted or switch to another node.

Could heartbeat v3 achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a proper Cluster Resource Manager like Pacemaker, in conjunction with a messaging layer like Heartbeat or Corosync. So no, Heartbeat v3 is not going to cut it, because it only does the messaging/heartbeat part.

If you search this site for other Heartbeat and Pacemaker-related questions you'll see that the best supported and most stable and feature-rich HA stack is based on Corosync and Pacemaker. It is not wise to use any other combination nowadays, unless you have a very specific reason and know exactly what you are doing.

Here is some material on Corosync and Pacemaker to get you started: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/ahead-pack-pacemaker-high-availability-stack?page=0,0 and http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/.

Comment: actually i don't want to involve pacemaker as CRM modules, because we have no complicated service/resource dependencies, only one service we need to monitor. so...is there any ways to make heartbeat to monitor service/resource?

Comment: No. Heartbeat v3 is not a cluster resource manager, just as Corosync is not a cluster resource manager. They provide messaging, cluster membership and quorum. They don't know or care about resources. You could go back to Heartbeat v2, which can do what you want, but it'll probably end in tears. You could also switch to Keepalived/VRRPD and not use a traditional cluster setup at all. Depends on the resources you want to have highly available.